# Is a diode destroyed after a Zener breakdown?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

The breakdown is a violent process, right? So does that make any irreversible destroy to the diode?

Could the diode remain intact after the voltage is removed?

Comment: The zener diode is designed so that it does "breakdown" when the reverse voltage exceeds a certain value. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zener breakdown isn't "violent" in itself. After all, Zener diodes are intended to operate permanently in breakdown mode!

The commonest reason that a diode (or transistor) fails after Zener breakdown is because of excessive heat generation in the component, not because of the breakdown itself.